# Aplicação Python web com Django - Bootstrap e Crispy só funcionam se tiver conexão com internet

Tags: javascript, python, aplicação-web, django, bootstrap

Minha aplicação utiliza essas duas frameworks Boostratp e Crispy, quando estou conectado na internet, tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém ao desconectar a internet o site perde toda parte de estilo.

Fazendo uma comparação com o Java, eu utilizo o Jquery, Bootstrap... fazendo referencia direta aos arquivos .js e .css locais e não preciso estar conectado para fazer uso desses recursos, teria alguma maneira de fazer o mesmo no Django?

Segue abaixo as linhas utilizadas no template:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda de todos.

Comment: Provavelmente é algum erro no seu código, que está fazendo algum pedido externo. Utilizo o Django em um projeto 100% offline e nunca tive tal problema.

Comment: O Django não faze nenhuma requis~ao externa -  esse probelma é claramente questão dos frameworks de front-end que devme ter URLs  hardcoded assumindo qeu a pessoa estará sempre online. Consulte a documetnação do bootstrap e do crispy para ver como trabalhar offline.

Comment: Agradeço as repostas, vocês estão corretos.  Eu utilizo Ubuntu em uma maquina virtual, provavelmente tive algum problema momentâneo.  Após remover o cabo de rede do notebook, consegui executar a aplicação estilizada sem nenhum problema.